# Extract some parameters from string

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, datagrid

How can I extract some parameters from two string and populate the datagrid by them ?

I have the config.txt file and there are two strings are repeated in pairs:

```
set interface "ethernet1/1.271" tag 271 zone "Ntg-Gom"
set interface ethernet1/1.271 ip 192.168.9.6/30
```

From this two string i need in extracting ethernet1/1.271 , 271 , 192.168.9.6/30. All this for populating such datagrid:

[image]

Obviously, I need a regular expression. Now I have the regexp for one parameter (here ethernet):

```
StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(opendialog.FileName);
string patternI = @"set interface (""ethernet\S+"")";

var matchesI =
Regex.Matches(reader2.ReadToEnd(), patternI).Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success)
                        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```

How to construct more complex regexp I do not know!  wasting a lot of time...

Comment: Anything in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) that helps.

Comment: like a dense forest! still try to find something there ...

Answer (score 2):

This will probably do it:

```
matchResults = Regex.Match(
                 subjectString, 
                 @"""(.*?)""\s+tag\s+(\d+).*?ip\s+([\d./]+)", 
                 RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: @HamZa early morning here... tks!